# I need to change time automatically

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter framework. I want to display date in a text box that should change its date according to the system time.Or i need to specify the date that must be valid for one year and it should change to next coming year.for example 20/06/2015(dd/mm/yyyy)-20/06/2016(dd/mm/yyyy) then it must be update the date and show us an alert message like 1 year is passed you need to update.
my field where the date is set is given below

```
<input type="date" value="start_date" name="start_date"/>
```

Comment: refer this http://harshen.github.io/jquery-countdownTimer/

Comment: thank u  for supporting :)

Comment: how do i use this idea in my project